# XML creation error

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am creating an application in VS 2010 using C# and I am having following error:

The first function (**funCheckStatus**) rotates in loop and whenever I apply debug point anywhere then all the XML files equal to loop number gets created.But when I remove the debug point , then only one file gets created and all other XMl files go missing.

The code is as follows:

```
//looping function for creation of XML files
public void funcCreateXML(List<int> iCode)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<iCode.Count; i++)
    {
        funChaeckStatus(iCode[i]);
    }
}

//Function To check status and create xml files according to the conditions
public void funCheckStatus ( int iExecCode )
{
    DataTable dtStatus = new DataTable();
    int iStatusCode;
    string strQry = @"Select ExecStatusCode from dbo.tExecutionReport where dbo.tExecutionReport.ExecRptID = " + iExecCode;
    objDal.funcSetDBConnection(strConn);
    dtStatus = objDal.funcSelect(strQry, "TAB").Tables[0];
    iStatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(dtStatus.Rows[0]["ExecStatusCode"].ToString());
    if ( iStatusCode == 4 )
    {
        objXMLCreator.CreateOCRExecutionXML(iExecCode);
    }
}

//Function to create xml file according to condition
public void CreateOCRExecutionXML ( int iOCRExecCode )
{
    try
    {
        objOCRXMLqueue = new OCRXMLPLCQueuor();
        objOCRXMLqueue.funOCRXMLQueueOpen();
        OCRExcutionXMLCreator(iOCRExecCode);//this function gather information and assign to xml data properties to create child nodes
        objOCRXMLqueue.funOCRAddXMLToQueue();
        objOCRXMLqueue.funOCRXMLQueueClose();
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}

//Function to crate xml doc declaration along with reading save xml path
public void funOCRXMLQueueOpen ()
{
    int iXMLRouter = 0;
    int iConnectionRouter = 0;
    //Create the XML declaration and append it to the XML document
    doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
    doc.AppendChild(dec);//create the root element
    root = doc.CreateElement(cnstStrXMLDtls);
    doc.AppendChild(root);

    StreamReader strmReader = new StreamReader("XXX.ini");
    string strLine = "";
    while ( strLine != null )
    {
        strLine = strmReader.ReadLine();
        if ( strLine != null )
        {
            if ( iXMLRouter > 0 )
            {
                if ( strLine.Trim() != "" )
                {
                    if ( lstFolderPath.Count != 3 )
                    {
                        string[] strSplit = strLine.Split(new string[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        lstFolderPath.Add(strSplit[1]);
                    }
                }
                else
                    iXMLRouter = 0;
            }
            if ( strLine == "[XML]" )
                iXMLRouter = 1;
        }
    }
    strmReader.Close();
}


//Function to add child node data to xml file.         
public void funOCRAddXMLToQueue ()
{
    XML = doc.CreateElement(cnstStrXML);
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrXMLCode, this.XMLCode.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrTrayEntryCode, this.TrayEntryCode.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrOrderCode, this.OrderCode.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrAssetCode, this.AssetCode.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrScripCode, this.ScripCode.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrTransType, this.TransType.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrQtyPlaced, this.QtyPlaced.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrQtySliced, this.QtySliced.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrIsSliceOnSuccess, this.IsSliceOnSuccess.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrQtyOpen, this.QtyOpen.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrQtyRemaining, this.TotalOrderQty.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrPriceLimit, this.PriceLimit.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrStopLimit, this.StopLimit.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrOrderType, this.OrderType.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrPlaceType, this.PlaceType.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrOrderStatus, this.OrderStatus.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrTgtXMLCode, this.TgtXMLCode.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrCreator, this.Creator.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrTrader, this.Trader.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrBroker, this.Broker.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrBrokerName, this.BrokerName.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrCreatedDateTime, this.CreatedDateTime.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrTradeDate, this.TradeDate.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrSettlementDate, this.SettlementDate.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrStrategy, this.Strategy.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrIsManual, this.IsManual.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrMktCode, this.MktCode.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrStartTime, this.StartTime.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrEndTime, this.EndTime.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrStatusCode, this.StatusCode.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrCreatedBy, this.CreatedBy.ToString());
    funOCRAddXMLField(clsGlobalConst.cnstStrCreatedDateTime, this.CreatedDateTime.ToString());

}
public void funOCRAddXMLField ( string strAttribute, string strValue )
{
    XmlElement PLCElement = doc.CreateElement(strAttribute);
    PLCElement.InnerText = strValue.Trim();
    XML.AppendChild(PLCElement);
    root.AppendChild(XML);
}

public void funOCRXMLQueueClose ()
{
    StringBuilder XMLFileName = new StringBuilder();
    XMLFileName.Append(cnstStrPLC);
    XMLFileName.Append(LoggedUser.ToUpper());
    XMLFileName.Append(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "_");
    XMLFileName.Append(DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "_");
    XMLFileName.Append(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "_");
    XMLFileName.Append(DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "_");
    XMLFileName.Append(DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + "_");

    if ( lstFolderPath.Count > 0 )
    {
        DirectoryInfo DIR = new DirectoryInfo(lstFolderPath[0].ToString());
        if ( !DIR.Exists )
            DIR.Create();
        doc.Save(DIR.FullName + "/" + XMLFileName.ToString() + ".xml");
    }

}
```

Comment: Try simplifying your code, and where is the loop on first method that you are talking about?

Comment: I have updated the code and added the function where looping occurs.Now please do check and help me.

Comment: This code is still too long, try removing code parts which are irrelevant to the problem. Then someone would bother trying to understand your code.